# Angular2 CLI issue with static resources and context

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have an Angular2 CLI project which has been working great.  I have a page like so: 
`http://localhost:4200/home`
and an image file here: `http://localhost:4200/img/myimage.jpg`. I would now like to change the context these  are both located under `/myapp/`.

So the new urls would be:

```
http://localhost:4200/myapp/myimage.png
http://localhost:4200/myapp/home
```

I've been able to get this to work for the home page, but static resources like images and css files aren't being served under the new urls.

Comment: Have you added `<base href='/myapp/'` in your index page, so that all resources are relative to that?

Comment: When I add the base href, all the http requests for the resources are correct and reflect `/myapp/` but the image and css files return 404 - Not found.

Comment: you have to make necessary changes for fixing the path, either put your resources there or , use fix path where you are using img\css.

Comment: the `\myapp` may change based on environment.  Shouldn't I be able to configure the built in server to serve them under whatever context I'd like?  For example, in a play App I can configure this by setting the application.context, and all my relative urls take this into account.

Comment: you may use environment setting to do the same, instead of doing it manually Cheers!

Comment: That sounds perfect!  Do you know how I would go about doing so?  thank you for your help.

Comment: you may also use `ng build --base-href /myUrl/` [check documentation here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

Comment: I've tried that half a dozen times.  As far as I can tell it does nothing :(

Comment: check the solution i have added.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up `base href` using environment file using `Angular CLI`

**index.html**

```
 <base href="{{environment.path}}"  />
```

**environment.ts**

```
  export const environment = {
    ...   
    path: '/myapp/'
 };
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This works great for changing the http requests made to be correct.  It returns 404s - resource not found when I do `ng serve`.  I think the server needs to be configured with a root resource directory as well.